# Learning Jasmine - toHaveBeenTriggered works on trigger("modal") but not on modal()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Both of these tests pass (i.e., action = "click")

```
// pass
var spyEvent = spyOnEvent( $("#checkout"), 'click' );
$("#checkout").click()
expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn("#checkout") 

// pass
var spyEvent = spyOnEvent( $("#checkout"), 'click' );
$("#checkout").trigger("click")
expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn("#checkout")
```

Yes very expected! However, in the below duo, the exact same concept where the action is now `modal`, only the trigger passes. Why?

```
// FAIL
var spyEvent = spyOnEvent( $("#checkout"), 'modal' );
$("#checkout").modal()
expect('modal').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn("#checkout") 

// pass
var spyEvent = spyOnEvent( $("#checkout"), 'modal' );
$("#checkout").trigger("modal")
expect('modal').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn("#checkout")
```

`.modal()` is from Twitter-bootstrap, which has been loaded correctly. There are no console errors.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR: you need to use `show.bs.modal`

That's because jQuery's `.trigger()` will create an event of the type you passed as parameter. This means that this

```
$('#foo').on('modal', someHandler);
$('#foo').trigger('modal');
```

will call `someHandler` as expected. However, this has nothing to do with Bootstrap's modal functionality, as the `modal` event here is defined by you on the go - so the test above would have been successful for

```
$('#foo').on('bar', someHandler);
$('#foo').trigger('bar');
```

as well. See [custom events in the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

As I understand, you want to bind the above handler to Bootstrap's modal functionality. What you're looking for is hidden at the [very bottom of the Bootstrap docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#events). *Note: these docs are for BS4, but the events are the same and it's much more readable than the [BS3 docs for Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples)*

Internally, Bootstrap triggers the `show.bs.modal` event when calling `.modal()` on an element, so you need to listen to that for the tests to make sense. There are multiple states that trigger events on each modal, the BS4 docs above have a table detailing these and when they are called.

Hope this helps!